# SSH times-out accessing a machine behind Open WRT from WAN but fine from LAN

Tags: openwrt

I recently reinstalled OpenWRT after I mistook a bug with cookies that caused a logon loop, for a forced entry into my router.

`Model    TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND v8
Firmware Version    OpenWrt Chaos Calmer 15.05.1 / LuCI 15.05-149-g0d8bbd2 Release (git-15.363.78009-956be55)`

Seemingly as a result, I cannot now access a machine in my LAN from the WAN.
I CAN access the same machine  from the same laptop, when it's on my LAN (it's set-up with the target machine's ssh cert, so logs straight in) but it times out when I try to access it from outside my LAN.

My Open WRT port forward:

`TargetMachineSSH
IPv4-TCP, UDP
From any host in wan
Via any router IP at port xxxx
IP 192.168.7.7, port 22 in lan`

To test external access I ssh'd into an Ubuntu virtual server at work, via work's VPN and from there ssh'd back to my home desktop machine, using external port xxxx, which failed/timed out. I used `ssh -l user -p xxxx mys.tat.ici.p` <= (my static IP)

As well as setting up a port forward, do I need a firewall rule for ssh? How would this look, given that I want to have a different external port for each of my machines and use port forwarding rules to resolve these to a machine's IP on port 22?

Something I know nothing about but which gets mentioned elsewhere is NAT - is this relevant and what should I check if it is?

Comment: what do you get if you use the -v option or -vv etc... for ssh to see some debugging messages.

Comment: I just tried ssh from my work's virtual server again but with `-v` and then `-vv`. Neither revealed anything interesting (here are the last 3 of 6 lines ): 

```debug1: Connecting to <static IP> [<static IP>] port xxxx.
 debug1: Connect to address <static IP> port xxxx: Connection timed out
ssh: Connect to address <static IP> port xxxx: Connection timed out```

Comment: I have also tried to interpret the firewall status page in LuCI (having reset the stats) but I'm not sure what to look for on the receiving end of the WAN side ssh port forward request.

Comment: Running `service sshd status` showed the successful login from within the LAN `Apr 27 14:41:44 <TARGET HOSTNAME> sshd[5025]: Accepted publickey for <USER> from 192.168.7.1 port 54973 ssh2: RSA SHA256: <CERT>
Apr 27 14:41:44 <TARGET HOSTNAME> sshd[5025]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user <USER> by (uid=0)` but nothing shows when access attempted from WAN on same machine. Does that imply firewall is the culprit?

Comment: Are you logging in to ssh with a password or a key?

Comment: I've tried both. The Mac has an ssh key to my home (in LAN) desktop machine - and used to work fine from LAN and WAN! - but I've also tried both my work (Ubuntu) server to access my home desktop and my home desktop calling itself but via my WAN static IP. Neither of the last two options has a key. None of these options work.